# How to show results of a static model in Modeling view with OpenModelica?

Tags: openmodelica

I am new to modelica. I would like to add two static numbers in OpenModelica and display the result in the Modeling view.

source1 = 10   # Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant

source2 = 20   # Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant

result = source1 + source2   # Modelica.Blocks.Math.Add

In order to do so, I created two sources with a constant real value and included a Math block for addition (also see full model code below).

[image]

I am able to run the simulation and select the result of the *add* block to show it as a plot in the *Plotting* view:

[image]

However, I would prefer to stay in the *Modeling* view and have **some display element**, showing the resulting value of 30:

[image]

**=> Are there display components in OpenModelica?** (could not find any)

Or do I always need to switch to the plotting view (even for static models that would not need to include a time variable)?

If there is no display component... is it possible to create it on my own? (Then components would need to be able to access simulation results.)

```
model demo
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant source1(k = 10)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-70, 52}, extent = {{-10, 10}, {10, -10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant source2(k = 20) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-70, -12}, extent = {{-10, 10}, {10, -10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.Add add annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-12, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(source1.y, add.u1) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-58, 52}, {-24, 52}, {-24, 16}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(source2.y, add.u2) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-58, -12}, {-24, -12}, {-24, 4}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "4.0.0")),
  Diagram);
end demo;
```

Related questions:

[How to show result of static model (=plain number) in Xcos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383253/how-to-show-result-of-static-model-plain-number-in-xcos)

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87166/python-framework-for-block-simulations-with-graphical-user-interface-like-openm

Answer (score 1):

There is `Modelica.Blocks.Interaction.Show.RealValue` that does something like what you want. The drawback is that this is not shown in the *modeling view*, but in the "Diagram Window" of the plotting view (which is in general used to show time-varying results/icon changes, with help of the simulation time scrubber.
This "Diagram Window" can be shown by clicking on the OMEdit looking button [image: icon] on the toolbar to show the diagram that can be animated in the Plotting perspective.

See here:
https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/omedit.html#omedit-diagram-window

```
model demo

  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant source1(k = 10)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-70, 52}, extent = {{-10, 10}, {10, -10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant source2(k = 20) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-70, -12}, extent = {{-10, 10}, {10, -10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.Add add annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-12, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interaction.Show.RealValue realValue annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {26, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(source1.y, add.u1) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-58, 52}, {-24, 52}, {-24, 16}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(source2.y, add.u2) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-58, -12}, {-24, -12}, {-24, 4}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(add.y, realValue.numberPort) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, 10}, {14.5, 10}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "4.0.0")),
  Diagram);

end demo;
```

So yeah, there are "display components" in the Modelica Standard Library (not only OpenModelica), but to see the dynamic result you have to use the plotting view.