# Is there a data frame data type in OpenModelica?

Tags: openmodelica, custom-data-type

I am new to OpenModelica and would like to create a model that processes tables, for example

**table_a**

| id_foo | id_baa | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 20 |

**table_b**

| id_foo | id_baa | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 200 |

Some *add* block should calculate

```
result = table_a + table_b
```

Expected result:

| id_foo | id_baa | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 110 |
| 1 | 2 | 220 |

What datatype / source should I use in OpenModelica to represent such tabular data?
(In python I would use pandas DataFrames.)

There seem to be some components for tabular structures/matrices (see entries below). However, they seem to serve a different purpose.

If there is no DataFrame equivalent in OpenModelica, how can I define a custom data type and use it it block diagrams?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Related questions:

[How to show results of a static model in Modeling view with OpenModelica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76359121/how-to-show-results-of-a-static-model-in-modeling-view-with-openmodelica)

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87166/python-framework-for-block-simulations-with-graphical-user-interface-like-openm