# How to show result of static model (=plain number) in Xcos?

Tags: scilab, flowchart, xcos

I add two numbers in Xcos and would like to show the result in the diagram. I managed to do so using a CSCOPE element and adding an extra CLOCK_c element:

[image]

However, I would prefer a **display element that simply shows the number**:

[image]

=> What component could I use for that?

If there is no existing display component for plain numbers, how can I create one?

**Related questions:**

[How to show results of a static model in Modeling view with OpenModelica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76359121/how-to-show-results-of-a-static-model-in-modeling-view-with-openmodelica)

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87166/python-framework-for-block-simulations-with-graphical-user-interface-like-openm

**xcos example file:**

xcos_demo.xcos

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<XcosDiagram debugLevel="0" finalIntegrationTime="30.0" integratorAbsoluteTolerance="1.0E-6" integratorRelativeTolerance="1.0E-6" toleranceOnTime="1.0E-10" maxIntegrationTimeInterval="100001.0" maximumStepSize="0.0" realTimeScaling="0.0" solver="1.0" background="-1" gridEnabled="1" title="Untitled"><!--Xcos - 2.0 - scilab-2023.1.0 - 20230523 0919-->
  <Array as="context" scilabClass="String[]"></Array>
  <mxGraphModel as="model">
    <root>
      <mxCell id="0:1:0"/>
      <mxCell id="0:2:0" parent="0:1:0"/>
      <BasicBlock id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7ff9" parent="0:2:0" interfaceFunctionName="CONST_m" blockType="d" dependsOnU="0" dependsOnT="0" simulationFunctionName="cstblk4_m" simulationFunctionType="C_OR_FORTRAN" style="CONST_m">
        <ScilabString as="exprs" height="1" width="1">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="1"/>
        </ScilabString>
        <ScilabDouble as="realParameters" height="0" width="0"/>
        <ScilabDouble as="integerParameters" height="0" width="0"/>
        <Array as="objectsParameters" scilabClass="ScilabList">
          <ScilabDouble height="1" width="1">
            <data line="0" column="0" realPart="1.0"/>
          </ScilabDouble>
        </Array>
        <ScilabInteger as="nbZerosCrossing" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
        </ScilabInteger>
        <ScilabInteger as="nmode" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
        </ScilabInteger>
        <ScilabDouble as="state" height="0" width="0"/>
        <ScilabDouble as="dState" height="0" width="0"/>
        <Array as="oDState" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
        <Array as="equations" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
        <mxGeometry as="geometry" x="170.0" y="270.0" width="40.0" height="40.0"/>
      </BasicBlock>
      <ExplicitOutputPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7ff8" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7ff9" ordering="1" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="1" initialState="0.0" style="ExplicitOutputPort;align=right;verticalAlign=middle;spacing=10.0;rotation=0" value=""/>
      <BigSom id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7ff1" parent="0:2:0" interfaceFunctionName="BIGSOM_f" blockType="c" dependsOnU="1" dependsOnT="0" simulationFunctionName="sum" simulationFunctionType="TYPE_2" style="BIGSOM_f">
        <ScilabString as="exprs" height="1" width="1">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="[1;1]"/>
        </ScilabString>
        <ScilabDouble as="realParameters" height="1" width="2">
          <data line="0" column="0" realPart="1.0"/>
          <data line="0" column="1" realPart="1.0"/>
        </ScilabDouble>
        <ScilabDouble as="integerParameters" height="0" width="0"/>
        <Array as="objectsParameters" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
        <ScilabInteger as="nbZerosCrossing" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
        </ScilabInteger>
        <ScilabInteger as="nmode" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
        </ScilabInteger>
        <ScilabDouble as="state" height="0" width="0"/>
        <ScilabDouble as="dState" height="0" width="0"/>
        <Array as="oDState" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
        <Array as="equations" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
        <mxGeometry as="geometry" x="430.0" y="310.0" width="40.0" height="60.0"/>
      </BigSom>
      <ExplicitInputPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7ff0" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7ff1" ordering="1" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="-1" initialState="0.0" style="ExplicitInputPort;align=left;verticalAlign=middle;spacing=10.0;rotation=0" value=""/>
      <ExplicitInputPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fef" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7ff1" ordering="2" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="-1" initialState="0.0" style="ExplicitInputPort;align=left;verticalAlign=middle;spacing=10.0;rotation=0" value=""/>
      <ExplicitOutputPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fee" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7ff1" ordering="1" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="-1" initialState="0.0" style="ExplicitOutputPort;align=right;verticalAlign=middle;spacing=10.0;rotation=0" value=""/>
      <BasicBlock id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fec" parent="0:2:0" interfaceFunctionName="CONST_m" blockType="d" dependsOnU="0" dependsOnT="0" simulationFunctionName="cstblk4_m" simulationFunctionType="C_OR_FORTRAN" style="CONST_m">
        <ScilabString as="exprs" height="1" width="1">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="1"/>
        </ScilabString>
        <ScilabDouble as="realParameters" height="0" width="0"/>
        <ScilabDouble as="integerParameters" height="0" width="0"/>
        <Array as="objectsParameters" scilabClass="ScilabList">
          <ScilabDouble height="1" width="1">
            <data line="0" column="0" realPart="1.0"/>
          </ScilabDouble>
        </Array>
        <ScilabInteger as="nbZerosCrossing" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
        </ScilabInteger>
        <ScilabInteger as="nmode" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
        </ScilabInteger>
        <ScilabDouble as="state" height="0" width="0"/>
        <ScilabDouble as="dState" height="0" width="0"/>
        <Array as="oDState" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
        <Array as="equations" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
        <mxGeometry as="geometry" x="170.0" y="360.0" width="40.0" height="40.0"/>
      </BasicBlock>
      <ExplicitOutputPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7feb" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fec" ordering="1" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="1" initialState="0.0" style="ExplicitOutputPort;align=right;verticalAlign=middle;spacing=10.0;rotation=0" value=""/>
      <BasicBlock id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fd6" parent="0:2:0" interfaceFunctionName="CSCOPE" blockType="c" dependsOnU="1" dependsOnT="0" simulationFunctionName="cscope" simulationFunctionType="C_OR_FORTRAN" style="CSCOPE;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;spacing=2;displayedLabel=">
        <ScilabString as="exprs" height="10" width="1">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15"/>
          <data line="1" column="0" value="-1"/>
          <data line="2" column="0" value="[]"/>
          <data line="3" column="0" value="[600;400]"/>
          <data line="4" column="0" value="-15"/>
          <data line="5" column="0" value="15"/>
          <data line="6" column="0" value="30"/>
          <data line="7" column="0" value="20"/>
          <data line="8" column="0" value="0"/>
          <data line="9" column="0" value=""/>
        </ScilabString>
        <ScilabDouble as="realParameters" height="1" width="4">
          <data line="0" column="0" realPart="0.0"/>
          <data line="0" column="1" realPart="-15.0"/>
          <data line="0" column="2" realPart="15.0"/>
          <data line="0" column="3" realPart="30.0"/>
        </ScilabDouble>
        <ScilabInteger as="integerParameters" height="1" width="15" intPrecision="sci_int32">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="-1"/>
          <data line="0" column="1" value="1"/>
          <data line="0" column="2" value="20"/>
          <data line="0" column="3" value="1"/>
          <data line="0" column="4" value="3"/>
          <data line="0" column="5" value="5"/>
          <data line="0" column="6" value="7"/>
          <data line="0" column="7" value="9"/>
          <data line="0" column="8" value="11"/>
          <data line="0" column="9" value="13"/>
          <data line="0" column="10" value="15"/>
          <data line="0" column="11" value="-1"/>
          <data line="0" column="12" value="-1"/>
          <data line="0" column="13" value="600"/>
          <data line="0" column="14" value="400"/>
        </ScilabInteger>
        <Array as="objectsParameters" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
        <ScilabInteger as="nbZerosCrossing" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
        </ScilabInteger>
        <ScilabInteger as="nmode" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
        </ScilabInteger>
        <ScilabDouble as="state" height="0" width="0"/>
        <ScilabDouble as="dState" height="0" width="0"/>
        <Array as="oDState" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
        <Array as="equations" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
        <mxGeometry as="geometry" x="610.0" y="320.0" width="40.0" height="40.0"/>
      </BasicBlock>
      <ExplicitInputPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fd5" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fd6" ordering="1" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="-1" initialState="0.0" style="ExplicitInputPort;align=left;verticalAlign=middle;spacing=10.0;rotation=0" value=""/>
      <ControlPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fd4" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fd6" ordering="1" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="1" initialState="0.0" style="ControlPort;align=center;verticalAlign=top;spacing=10.0;rotation=90" value=""/>
      <BasicBlock id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fd1" parent="0:2:0" interfaceFunctionName="CLOCK_c" blockType="h" dependsOnU="0" dependsOnT="0" simulationFunctionName="csuper" simulationFunctionType="DEFAULT" style="CLOCK_c">
        <ScilabDouble as="exprs" height="0" width="0"/>
        <ScilabDouble as="realParameters" height="0" width="0"/>
        <ScilabDouble as="integerParameters" height="0" width="0"/>
        <Array as="objectsParameters" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
        <ScilabInteger as="nbZerosCrossing" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
        </ScilabInteger>
        <ScilabInteger as="nmode" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
          <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
        </ScilabInteger>
        <ScilabDouble as="state" height="0" width="0"/>
        <ScilabDouble as="dState" height="0" width="0"/>
        <Array as="oDState" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
        <Array as="equations" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
        <mxGeometry as="geometry" x="610.0" y="180.0" width="40.0" height="40.0"/>
        <SuperBlockDiagram as="child" background="-1" gridEnabled="1" title="">
          <Array as="context" scilabClass="String[]"></Array>
          <mxGraphModel as="model">
            <root>
              <mxCell id="7ca5d227:1887764bffc:-7fd1"/>
              <mxCell id="7ca5d227:1887764bffd:-7fd1" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffc:-7fd1"/>
              <EventOutBlock id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fbc" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffd:-7fd1" interfaceFunctionName="CLKOUT_f" blockType="d" dependsOnU="0" dependsOnT="0" simulationFunctionName="output" simulationFunctionType="DEFAULT" style="">
                <ScilabString as="exprs" height="1" width="1">
                  <data line="0" column="0" value="1"/>
                </ScilabString>
                <ScilabDouble as="realParameters" height="0" width="0"/>
                <ScilabInteger as="integerParameters" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
                  <data line="0" column="0" value="1"/>
                </ScilabInteger>
                <Array as="objectsParameters" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
                <ScilabInteger as="nbZerosCrossing" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
                  <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
                </ScilabInteger>
                <ScilabInteger as="nmode" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
                  <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
                </ScilabInteger>
                <ScilabDouble as="state" height="0" width="0"/>
                <ScilabDouble as="dState" height="0" width="0"/>
                <Array as="oDState" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
                <Array as="equations" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
                <mxGeometry as="geometry" x="399.0" y="162.0" width="20.0" height="20.0"/>
              </EventOutBlock>
              <ControlPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fbb" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fbc" ordering="1" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="1" initialState="0.0" style="" value=""/>
              <BasicBlock id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fba" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffd:-7fd1" interfaceFunctionName="EVTDLY_c" blockType="d" dependsOnU="0" dependsOnT="0" simulationFunctionName="evtdly4" simulationFunctionType="C_OR_FORTRAN" style="">
                <ScilabString as="exprs" height="2" width="1">
                  <data line="0" column="0" value="0.1"/>
                  <data line="1" column="0" value="0.1"/>
                </ScilabString>
                <ScilabDouble as="realParameters" height="1" width="2">
                  <data line="0" column="0" realPart="0.1"/>
                  <data line="0" column="1" realPart="0.1"/>
                </ScilabDouble>
                <ScilabDouble as="integerParameters" height="0" width="0"/>
                <Array as="objectsParameters" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
                <ScilabInteger as="nbZerosCrossing" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
                  <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
                </ScilabInteger>
                <ScilabInteger as="nmode" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
                  <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
                </ScilabInteger>
                <ScilabDouble as="state" height="0" width="0"/>
                <ScilabDouble as="dState" height="0" width="0"/>
                <Array as="oDState" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
                <Array as="equations" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
                <mxGeometry as="geometry" x="320.0" y="232.0" width="40.0" height="40.0"/>
              </BasicBlock>
              <ControlPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb9" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fba" ordering="1" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="1" initialState="0.0" style="" value=""/>
              <CommandPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb8" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fba" ordering="1" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="1" initialState="0.1" style="" value=""/>
              <SplitBlock id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb7" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffd:-7fd1" interfaceFunctionName="CLKSPLIT_f" blockType="d" dependsOnU="0" dependsOnT="0" simulationFunctionName="split" simulationFunctionType="DEFAULT" style="">
                <ScilabDouble as="exprs" height="0" width="0"/>
                <ScilabDouble as="realParameters" height="0" width="0"/>
                <ScilabDouble as="integerParameters" height="0" width="0"/>
                <Array as="objectsParameters" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
                <ScilabInteger as="nbZerosCrossing" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
                  <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
                </ScilabInteger>
                <ScilabInteger as="nmode" height="1" width="1" intPrecision="sci_int32">
                  <data line="0" column="0" value="0"/>
                </ScilabInteger>
                <ScilabDouble as="state" height="0" width="0"/>
                <ScilabDouble as="dState" height="0" width="0"/>
                <Array as="oDState" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
                <Array as="equations" scilabClass="ScilabList"/>
                <mxGeometry as="geometry" x="380.71066" y="172.0" width="0.3333333333333333" height="0.3333333333333333"/>
              </SplitBlock>
              <ControlPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb6" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb7" ordering="1" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="1" initialState="0.0" style="" value=""/>
              <CommandPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb5" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb7" ordering="1" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="1" initialState="-1.0" style="" value=""/>
              <CommandPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb4" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb7" ordering="2" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="1" initialState="-1.0" style="" value=""/>
              <CommandControlLink id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb3" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffd:-7fd1" source="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb8" target="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb6" style="" value="">
                <mxGeometry as="geometry">
                  <mxPoint as="sourcePoint" x="340.0" y="226.29"/>
                  <Array as="points">
                    <mxPoint x="340.0" y="172.0"/>
                  </Array>
                  <mxPoint as="targetPoint" x="380.71" y="172.0"/>
                </mxGeometry>
              </CommandControlLink>
              <CommandControlLink id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb2" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffd:-7fd1" source="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb5" target="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fbb" style="" value="">
                <mxGeometry as="geometry">
                  <mxPoint as="sourcePoint" x="380.71" y="172.0"/>
                  <Array as="points"></Array>
                  <mxPoint as="targetPoint" x="399.0" y="172.0"/>
                </mxGeometry>
              </CommandControlLink>
              <CommandControlLink id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb1" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffd:-7fd1" source="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb4" target="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fb9" style="" value="">
                <mxGeometry as="geometry">
                  <mxPoint as="sourcePoint" x="380.71" y="172.0"/>
                  <Array as="points">
                    <mxPoint x="380.71" y="302.0"/>
                    <mxPoint x="340.0" y="302.0"/>
                  </Array>
                  <mxPoint as="targetPoint" x="340.0" y="277.71"/>
                </mxGeometry>
              </CommandControlLink>
            </root>
          </mxGraphModel>
          <mxCell as="defaultParent" id="7ca5d227:1887764bffd:-7fd1" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffc:-7fd1"/>
        </SuperBlockDiagram>
      </BasicBlock>
      <CommandPort id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fd0" parent="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fd1" ordering="1" dataType="REAL_MATRIX" dataColumns="1" dataLines="1" initialState="-1.0" style="CommandPort;align=center;verticalAlign=bottom;spacing=10.0;rotation=90" value=""/>
      <ExplicitLink id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fed" parent="0:2:0" source="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7ff8" target="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7ff0" style="ExplicitLink" value="">
        <mxGeometry as="geometry">
          <mxPoint as="sourcePoint" x="44.0" y="20.0"/>
          <Array as="points"></Array>
          <mxPoint as="targetPoint" x="-4.0" y="20.0"/>
        </mxGeometry>
      </ExplicitLink>
      <ExplicitLink id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fea" parent="0:2:0" source="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7feb" target="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fef" style="ExplicitLink" value="">
        <mxGeometry as="geometry">
          <mxPoint as="sourcePoint" x="44.0" y="20.0"/>
          <Array as="points"></Array>
          <mxPoint as="targetPoint" x="-4.0" y="40.0"/>
        </mxGeometry>
      </ExplicitLink>
      <ExplicitLink id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fd2" parent="0:2:0" source="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fee" target="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fd5" style="ExplicitLink" value="">
        <mxGeometry as="geometry">
          <mxPoint as="sourcePoint" x="44.0" y="30.0"/>
          <Array as="points"></Array>
          <mxPoint as="targetPoint" x="-4.0" y="20.0"/>
        </mxGeometry>
      </ExplicitLink>
      <CommandControlLink id="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fce" parent="0:2:0" source="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fd0" target="7ca5d227:1887764bffb:-7fd4" style="CommandControlLink" value="">
        <mxGeometry as="geometry">
          <mxPoint as="sourcePoint" x="20.0" y="44.0"/>
          <Array as="points"></Array>
          <mxPoint as="targetPoint" x="20.0" y="-4.0"/>
        </mxGeometry>
      </CommandControlLink>
    </root>
  </mxGraphModel>
  <mxCell as="defaultParent" id="0:2:0" parent="0:1:0"/>
</XcosDiagram>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the AFFICH_m block (https://help.scilab.org/AFFICH_m). However, be warned that you still have to run the simulation to see the value:
[image]